# Как сделать так, чтобы ссылки менялись автоматически?

Tags: php

У меня есть локальный сервер localhost. На нём есть сайт с php-файлами, находящимися на разных уровнях. При переходе со страницы одного уровня на страницу другого уровня все подключённые стили летят, так как ссылки на них относительно нового адреса меняются. Как сделать так, чтобы эти ссылки менялись автоматически?
P.S. Думаю, что это как-то можно сделать, указав абсолютный, а не относительный адрес. Но тогда при переносе на другой сервер всё тоже полетит. Может, можно как-то указать ссылки относительно хоста?

Comment: В теге `<head>` положите `<base href="localhost">` и потом подключайте стили вот так: `<link href="/css/style.css"`, тоесть просто начинайте со слэша.

Comment: @Diman2000zver используйте магическую константу **__DIR__**. Пример подключения:  `include __DIR__ . 'file.php';`